# How to get greater accuracy when converting the QTableItem to QDoubleSpinBox?

Tags: c++, qt

There is a piece of code:

```
std::cout << static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(ui->InitialValuesTable->cellWidget(2, 1))->value() << std::endl;
```

Here I get the value of a cell of a table. Cells are QDoubleSpinBox.
The table values have a precision of 15 decimals. However I am getting after execution of this line of code only 6 digits after point. How to get table value with a precision of 15 decimals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `std::cout` to output more decimals, you can use [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) to tell it to do so:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox*>(ui->InitialValuesTable->cellWidget(2, 1))->value() << std::endl;
```

Note the `15` in the above is the *precision*, and not the amount of decimals. Also note a `double` *generally* only has 15 digits *precision*, so showing more digits is actually lying to yourself and/or the user.

---

You can use the `QDoubleSpinBox`'s [`decimals`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop) property to set its display precision.